# Element jumps beyond parent even when margin is set to percent

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with setting an element at a specific position no matter which device you're viewing it, so it stays consistent.

This is my code in question:

#### HTML

```html
<div class="gradient-background" style="margin-top: -100px;">
    <div class="cd-intro">
      <h1 class="cd-headline clip" style="z-index:1;">
        <span>We</span>
        <span class="cd-words-wrapper">
          <b class="is-visible">help people.</b>
          <b>make their lives better.</b>
          <b>are Streamlined.</b>
        </span>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-hint">
      <img src="Images/scroll-down.png" style="width: 70px;">
    </div>
  </div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.gradient-background {
  height: 115%;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradientBG 15s ease infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scroll-hint {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 90%;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding why this doesn't work. From what I understand, when in CSS you put margin in percent, it calculates it relative to the parent element. So then, why does it jump out of gradient-background? (Element in question: scroll-hint)

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that it is not something else in your HTML/CSS that is causing this problem? It seems to stay in position with the excerpt you provided.

```css
.gradient-background {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  animation: gradientBG 15s ease infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scroll-hint {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 90%;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-background">
  <div class="cd-intro">
    <h1 class="cd-headline clip">
      <span>We</span>
      <span class="cd-words-wrapper">
        <b class="is-visible">help people.</b>
        <b>make their lives better.</b>
        <b>are Streamlined.</b>
      </span>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-hint">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0jq3em67/1/

P.S. I changed some of the percentages and inline styles in the above fiddle and snippet.

Comment: https://streamlined.tech/dev.php

The arrow overflows to the Our Product section.

Comment: Try this for your ```scroll-hint``` class. ```.scroll-hint {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}```

Comment: I mean sure, this will work, but absolute will always work. It's a brute-force method. What I'm trying to understand is why my solution doesn't work, when it should.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through provided link. Your code is as follows

```
.scroll-hint {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 90%;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}
```

Your html code is as follow

```
<div class="gradient-background">
  <div class="cd-intro">
    <h1 class="cd-headline clip">
      <span>We</span>
      <span class="cd-words-wrapper">
        <b class="is-visible">help people.</b>
        <b>make their lives better.</b>
        <b>are Streamlined.</b>
      </span>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-hint">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here you applied margin to the `.scroll-hint` that means it takes margin from it's the adjacent element which is `.cd-intro`. According to your code in the given website link CSS box-model for `.cd-intro` is as in below picture.

[image]

and the CSS box-model for `.scroll-hint` is as follows.

[image]

So `.cd-intro` is having some Height+Padding+Margin and then the margin of `.scroll-hint` will start from the endpoint of `.cd-intro` in th DOM.

That's why you can't see that as you expected. Change that margin that you applied to some lesser % value, there you go... You can see that as in below picture.

[image]

Comment: I've already tried lesser % values, but they do not scale well with Desktop/Mobile. On desktop is looks fine, on mobile odd, and the opposite for higher values.